How to use own springboot project as a library in another
I would like to add a package from one springboot project to another. I had generated jar file from 'mylibrary' project - exported to the hdd - imported to the cadmdb2 'project', but after run maven install I get the error that the class Company from 'mylibrary' project doesn't exist. What is wrong? Please find screenshot below.

pom.xml (cadmdb2)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.krzysztofskul</groupId>
    <artifactId>cadmdb</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cadmdb</name>
    <description>CADmedica spring boot application | hospital planning and calculation</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thedeanda/lorem -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thedeanda</groupId>
            <artifactId>lorem</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>pl.krzysztofskul</groupId>
          <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

after add mylibrary dependency:


how did you add that dependency to the other project?

if you're using maven anyway just build the library (mvn clean install), and in the pom of the new project add it as dependency, it'll find it in your local repository and import correctly

I tried to add as a dependency in pom.xml file; also I tried add a JAR file to java build path -> projects/libraries ->class path

What do you see when you navigate to the cadmdb2 project maven dependencies, go to mylibrary, and open the code there (using eclipse decompiler) - what classes are there? Is there a chance the version you imported does not have that class?

I can see only mylibrary icon [without test code] *please find a screenshot on main post

A spring boot project (or more accurate the resulting jar) can not be used as a dependency for other projects because it's not a default jar anymore... You have to split up that project into a multi module build...and extract the parts you would like to consume in another project..

Hmm.. so how to do it exactly? Create a new project pl.krzysztofskul.cadmdb2/mylibrary? My aim is to have autmaticaly updates in one project, when I make changes insie second project..

Execute the mvn install task in your connected project. Then use it as a regular dependency in the pom.xml file:
...
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>{groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>{artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>{version}</version>
</dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...

If you want to directly connect from the file, you can use this method, but it is not recommended. :)
<dependency>
  <artifactId>{libArtifactId}</artifactId>
  <groupId>{libGroupid</groupId>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <version>{libVersion}</version>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/{libName}.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

Note: in the above example, the JAR file should be placed in the root of the project in the "libs" directory.

Still doesn't work. The same error. I have found also that when try to run main class I also get the error: Error: Could not find or load main class pl.krzysztofskul.cadmdb.CadmdbApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.krzysztofskul.cadmdb.CadmdbApplication

Can you share pom.xml CADMDB2?

Yes, I have edited my main post. The Error: Could not find or load main class pl.krzysztofskul.cadmdb.CadmdbApplication is caused because of mcn install failure.

Another questionm is it posiible to indicate the branch in ?

@krzysztofskul "branch" like in git branch? Dependency mechanism can't know anything about that, if you have multiple branches that you're upkeeping at the same time you should give them different version numbers, so that there is no uncertanity about what version of the code you're importing

Do you mean in the Git branch or what?
